# Unzip / untar `pip` wheel without compiling or installing

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I want to download a source tarball from PyPI and extract it.

`pip install -t .` downloads and installs package.
`pip download numpy && tar -xf numpy*` doesn't work on Windows. No cross-platform compatibility.

I expect a command to download the source distribution from PyPI and extract it automatically, in 1 command.

Note: only extract the source. No installing / compiling.
Note 2: It should work on Windows, Linux and MacOS.
Note 3: The solution should use only one command: `pip`. No other command should be used.

Comment: Why don't you want to use other commands?

Comment: Cross platform compatibility. I want to run my script on as maybe devices as possible. So the less the commands I use, the more systems I can support

Comment: Since Python will already be installed on the machine, why not write a Python script for it? There is built-in tar file support in Python so you wouldn't need any additional libraries for it.

Comment: As others have commented, if you use only Python commands to unpack then you still are cross platforms. `python -m zipfile --extract numpy-xxx.whl path/to/some/directory`. -- Asking for just 1 command seems ridiculous to me. But anyway you can write your own Python script so that it is only 1 command, it is quite straightforward.